# Given random variable $F_{x}(n)=P(X=n)=\frac{c}{n(n+1)}$ calculate $c$ and $P(X>m)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given random variable $F_{x}(n)=P(X=n)=\frac{c}{n(n+1)}$ calculate $c$ and $P(X>m)$ for $m=1,2,3...$.

First of all $\lim\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_{x}(n)=1 $, so $$\lim\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_{x}(n)=\frac{c}{n(n+1)} + \frac{c}{(n+1)(n+2)} ... \leq c(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} ...)\leq c$$

So $c$ has to be less than $1$. But how do I go about calculating  $P(X>m)$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}=1$ is correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ so: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}1-\frac{1}{m+1}=1$

Comment: Thanks. I got a simple question though:
What If I had to calculate the expected value for this random variable? It would be $\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{c}{n+1}$, therefore it would not exists, right?

Comment: It diverges, but saying that is does not exists goes quite far. Usually for nonnegative rvs the convention is practizised that in a case like this the expectation is  $+\infty$. If $X$ is a real-valued rv then $X_{+}:=\max\left(X,0\right)$ and
$X_{-}:=\max\left(-X,0\right)$ are nonnegative real-valued rvs with
$X=X_{+}-X_{-}$ and $\left|X\right|=X_{+}+X_{-}$. One says that
$EX$ does not exist if $EX_{+}=EX_{-}=+\infty$. If $EX_{+}=\infty$ and $EX_{-}<\infty$ then $EX=+\infty$ and if
$EX_{+}<\infty$ and $EX_{-}=\infty$ then $EX=-\infty$. In the other cases $EX=EX_{+}-EX_{-}$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to estimate $c$ here but to find it. That is, you have to find $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and then find $c=\frac{1}{S}$.

After that $P\{x>m\}=c\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Comment: So this sum... $$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ ...is equal to one. Therefore $c=1$. 

$P\{X>m\}=c\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1-c\sum\limits_{i=0}^m \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1-(1-\frac{1}{m})=\frac{1}{m}$. 

Is this correct?